# Custom eCommerce Pop-Up?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, paypal, e-commerce

I am developing a site for a client and I need the ability to add a pop up on the home page that allows the user to enter their email/payment info and  then click a button to purchase a ticket for an event. I've looked into WooCommerce and WP-eCommerce but I can't find a way to do this.

Does anyone know a way that I can integrate this into a custom site built on top of Wordpress.

--I know how to make a form pop up when clicking a button, I just need to know some way to integrate a payment gateway into a custom form.

--It needs to be able to take credit card info, if It can work just with credit cards (not any other payment form) that fine. I just need something that works

Answer (score 0):

The WooCommerce + [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) combination is "something that works" but you would have to customize the part where it happens within a pop-up.

This can be done with custom template files and hooks into WordPress / WooCommerce to build that out how you need it.

Answer (score 0):

For Processing Payment WooCommerce have it's own file and Method. 
The Method took the Info (Payment Info i.e : Card Number, Validity,Name etc)as parameter. Let me try to draw the pseudo for you below: 
What you need for purchasing the event ticket as per your user story: 
--> Get the Email / payment info at the pop up form
--> While submit the form, pass the Info user entered to the method which responsible for the Payment process. 
You might need to skip the cart part.

Visit [woocommerce payment Api](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/) details page for better understanding,how you utilize / Extend  their code. 
Hope this will help.